# Doing calculations in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a database for InvoiceItems.The database is something like this

```
 === InvoiceItems ===
  id
  item_name
  quantity
  unit_price
  item_tax
  total
```

As I have made Model and CRUD for invoiceitems,I can easily insert and update the forms.Now as the business logic goes behind the database it needs to be automated.So according to the database when I will insert the quantity,unit_price and item_tax to the form,it should give me the result of total.

```
for example let us take the quantity as 20,
unit_price as 50,
item_tax as 10%,
so the result should be like this 20X50 = 1000+item_tax(10%)
                                        = 1000+100 = 1100;
                                        So in place of total 1100 should come.
```

Comment: so what exactly do you want help with?

Comment: Actually I want to know how the calculation part can be done in Yii.

Comment: where do you want the result to be shown?

Comment: I want the result to show in view file.Is it possible to do?If yes then how..

Comment: it is possible, but which view? in the detailview? or in the _form itself?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Yii, I'll assume you have jQuery loading. I'l also assume you have the tax value pre-populated with a percentage value (e.g. '10'), but this should be enough of a start if it's not.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#quantity, #unit_price").on('change',function(event){
    var $subtotal = $("#quantity").val() * $("#unit_price").val();
    var $total = $subtotal + ($subtotal  * $("#tax").val() / 100);
    $("#total").val($total);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few steps to do that:

1. First create a button, that says something like `Calculate Total`
2. When this button is clicked, call a javascript function, that reads the values of the inputs
3. In this function calculate the total
4. And then populate the `total` field

Edit:(without button)

1. Call function to calculate total when the value has been entered, i.e. `onBlur` event, or maybe use `onChange` event.
2. And then populate `total` field

Read more on Javascript events, to know which event is best suited for your application's flow. Read up on the differences, of the events i've mentioned.

Comment: Ok..thats good,But is there any method by which without click on any button the total can populate?

Comment: i don't do a lot of javascript myself, so i won't be able to answer that properly. but in my opinion the total should be calculated only when the user is done filling the fields. so having a button is good, that's what most websites do, it's good ux. Without a button is possible, but i won't be able to give a good answer for that.

Comment: hey, i added an edit, yesterday, to give you hints about how to proceed without button, check it.